# why do string.strip() function removed the character i want in some words and remove none in others

Tags: python, string, strip

i am trying to remove the '\n' characters a string because when i read the lines from a file it include the '\n' characters!!
input:

```
with open('names.txt', mode='r') as file:
    list_of_names = file.readlines()
    print(list_of_names)
    for name in list_of_names:
        list_of_names.remove(name)
        name = name.strip('\n')
        list_of_names.append(name)
    print(list_of_names)
```

output:

```
['Aang\n', 'Zuko\n', 'Appa\n', 'Katara\n', 'Sokka\n', 'Momo\n', 'Uncle Iroh\n', 'Toph']
['Zuko\n', 'Katara\n', 'Momo\n', 'Toph', 'Appa', 'Uncle Iroh', 'Sokka', 'Aang']
```

Comment: You can just do `r = [i.strip() for i in list_of_names]`.

Comment: Also, you are iterating over a list and removing items from it at the same time. Do not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are modifying the list while iterating over it, halfway through the loop, `list_of_names.remove(name)` is trying to remove the wrong element. This is also why the order of the list changes. This is unnecessarily complex.

Instead of modifying the old list, consider simply appending to a new, empty list.

```
with open('names.txt', mode='r') as f:
    list_of_names = f.readlines()
    new_list_of_names = []
    print(list_of_names)
    for name in list_of_names:
        name = name.strip('\n')
        new_list_of_names.append(name)
    print(new_list_of_names)
```

Or, for shorter code, use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    list_of_names = f.readlines()
    new_list_of_names = [name.strip('\n') for name in list_of_names]
    print(list_of_names)
    print(new_list_of_names)
```

(**Note**: `mode='r'` is redundant because the default mode is read.)